# How it this possible to set height percentage of widget by refering the parent widget height in flutterflow flutter

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

How it this possible to set height percentage of widget by refering the parent widget height in flutterflow flutter

as consider example like,
parent widget height is 70%
so the child widget 100% will be 70% of the parent widget not 100% of the screen height

I try to search on flutterflow website and on stackoverflow i did not found any solution for that